# Unable to invoke Safari browser with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, safari

OS : MAC Sierra (10.12.1)

Safari Version: 10.0.1(12602.2.14.0.7)

Selenium-server-standalone version :3.3.1

Unable to invoke Safari browser with above configuration, can any one help to resolve this.

Followed some solutions online and tried to invoke with

> /usr/bin/safaridriver -port 0

though prompting Password, unable to authenticate this.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: Problem with MAC OS configuration, IT Support team resolved the issue. Thanks.